# Teamcity agent configure nodejs version

Tags: teamcity

How can I configure the version of node that the teamcity agent uses when running my deployment?

Currently the agent uses node version 16.13 --> but I want it to use an older version.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/nodejs.html):

> TeamCity uses `node:lts` by default, or, if there is an `.nvmrc` file inside your project, it will search for the image specification there.